# Visual Studio 2012 has no debugging options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, remote-debugging

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 Express (Update 4) with Windows Azure Tools 2.5. I have the Remote Tools installed for Visual Studio 2012 Express Update 4.

I'm running some WorkerRoles on Windows Azure, and I need to do some debugging on the staging version.

My understanding is that I can connect to Azure using the Database Explorer in VS and find the process and attach the debugger to it. I've been following various tutorials around the net that all say the same as this one (which is actually very well written): http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/11/02/remote-debug-windows-azure-cloud-service.aspx

The problem I have is that when I hit publish, and go to advanced settings, there's no option to enable debugging. According to everywhere it should look like this:

[image: It should look like this]

But I don't have those options:

[image: but it looks like this]

Later, when I go to the cloud services in the database explorer, and I right click on the role I want to attach to, there's no option to "Attach Debugger":

[image: No option to attach debugger]

Is this a limitation of VS2012 Express?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers,
Chris

---

**EDIT:**

As in the tutorial I have the Build Configuration set to Debug:

[image: Build configuration set to debug]

Comment: I am running VS 2013 Ultimate and seeing the same issue.

Comment: what does the screen for the Common Settings Tab look like?  As is mentioned in the article you referenced, you must change the build configuration to "Debug" .

Comment: @Claies The point I think is that the option to set the build configuration to debug when **publishing** no longer exists.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I'm not quite sure that's the case; the screen posted in the question isn't on the tab which shows if the setting is available or not; the Enable Remote Debugger option is tied to the Debug Configuration, but they are separate settings.

Comment: Changing the configuration to "Debug" was most definitely available on a test machine I just spun up, running Windows Azure Tools 2.5.

Comment: As far as I've tried, the Build Configuration option does exist and it's set to Debug (as in the tutorial). I've updated the question to reflect this. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I realise that this may/may not help others experiencing this problem.*

I solved the problem by completely uninstalling all the different versions of Visual Studio, .NET, SQL Server tools. I had tried so many different versions of things that Azure tools and things may not have been applying to the correct version.

**Here's the important bit:**

The version I'm working with now is Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

If re-installing doesn't solve the problem, Visual Studio 2012 Pro has these features.